# In Excel VBA how can I determine how many worksheet tabs are currently within view across the bottom of the window..?

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel VBA 2007 how can I determine which worksheet tabs are currently within view across the bottom of the window..? I do not see any object properties for such a thing.

Please note this question is NOT asking *whether or not any worksheets are currently hidden*, rather I'm looking for the number of tabs that are currently *shown in the tab bar* at the bottom of the window.

Ideally, any such function should return a starting worksheet index number or name, and either an ending index or count, or perhaps the `Range` of worksheets for the currently shown tabs.

I see the `ScrollWorkbookTabs` function, but it doesn't really apply to this. Also the `worksheet.Tab` object has no related properties, like something called `.WithinView`, for instance.

I would include a code example, but I can't even find a place to start with this.

Comment: I don't know of anything within the object model, but just have to ask out of curiosity, what's the use case for this?

Comment: I thought as much; I've been searching the objects in the Locals window in Stop mode for almost an hour. What I wish to do is provide a visual cue when tabs are added with a color change that scrolls back and forth once across the tabs, like a lens flare. But it should only happen to the tabs which are currently within view; it doesn't make sense to do across all of them if 100+ tabs were added. I could certainly just always do it for a fixed number such as 10, but I'd rather have the exact count/range.

Comment: Would the close-voters please explain, so I can understand if/what I've done improperly to deserve such votes..? In the past I've seen a banner such as when the OP might be a duplicate, but currently I see no indication for the reasons for the current close-votes.

Comment: Maybe just "flare" up to the first ~30 sheets and slow the flare change the flare speed based on the number of sheets present. Funky idea, I kind of like it

Comment: You can't know that from the object model. The width of the "tab bar" depends on the width of the main window *and* the user-adjustable width of the horizontal scrollbar panel: I can't think of any way to query these objects without some serious Win32 hacks.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Not a bad idea. The scroll speed could include an acceleration factor with a bell-curve, so if there are many tabs it scrolls fast in the middle but slowly at the end, and then snaps back to the first newly added tab. As you say, I kind of like it. =-)

Comment: @spinjector Not sure if this fits the bill, but have you thought of making the <=5 sheets preceding and the <=5 sheets after the current sheet have tapered color?  you would only need to know the position of the currently indexed sheet in the overall sheets.count.  e.g., all sheets tab color is default and the saturation of your desired color is 100% for current sheet, 80% for left/right, out to 20% for 5 out from current sheet.

Comment: @Mathieu Guindon, yes I figured it would boil down to some API wizardry. And now that you say it, of course you're correct about the object model; sometimes the properties & functions can be hidden...unless one wants to bang one's head on TLBINF32 or VSTLBINF or the myriad utilities built around them. Given the choice between that and the API, I think I'd choose the latter.

Comment: You might be able to use Microsoft UI Automation, and check `IsOffscreen` property for each of the tab item controls in the document. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.automationelementinformation.isoffscreen?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you asked for, but here's my take on an answer. It makes sort of a "racing" yellow color to a four worksheet tabs from left to right. I chose not to flare from the active worksheet because the scroll bar could have been scrolled left or right and not be showing that active worksheet during the animation.
To keep the example simple I chose not to preserve any existing sheet colors but that can implemented if necessary.

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare PtrSafe Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As LongPtr)

Private Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

    '' "lens flare" when adding a new worksheet

    Dim delay As Long

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count + 3

        ''color tab yellow
        If i <= Sheets.Count Then
            Sheets(i).Tab.Color = vbYellow
        End If

        ''clear trailing tab color
        If i > 3 Then
            Sheets(i - 3).Tab.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
        End If

        ''pause for 150ms -> 30ms
        delay = IIf(Sheets.Count < Round((160 - 30) / 5), 160 - (Sheets.Count * 5), 30)
        Sleep delay

    Next i

End Sub
```